# Running into errors following a selenium chromedriver web automation tutorial

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm fairly new to programing and have been trying my best to get a grasp of different concepts. I've made a few games and twitter bots, and am looking at trying some web scraping/automation.

I have been following along with this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7LEWxX4AVI
and have gotten stuck trying to enter text into the search bar. I'm using chrome Version 81.0.4044.129 and have the right Chromedriver to go with it.

This is my code from the tutorial -

```py
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://youtube.com')


searchbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]')

searchbox.send_keys('Type Type Type')


searchButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search-icon-legacy"]')

searchButton.click()
```

It opens up chrome but does not enter anything into the search bar

https://gyazo.com/68da5e2e2340265ae50125558ed8ed11

I get these errors that open in a new window
and I get these in my python shell

https://gyazo.com/e9d702ef1ec4e4bc422ae537a3b59fbe

any advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: I think you are try to enter text into the search bar even before it has loaded completely on the webpage. Error that you are getting is Element is not intractable. Try to use explicit wait before you enter the text in the search bar. Also paste the error in the Description and not as an image.